# Best practices for calling Windows API functions from Go

Tags: windows, go

I'm writing my first real Go program under Windows, and I'm trying to learn best practices for calling Windows API functions. After viewing multiple examples, I put together a simple test of calling the `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` function.

That all works, but there's one oddity that nobody mentions: upon successful return, the `err` variable is set to `"Operation completed successfully"`.

It's easy enough to set `err = nil` if the function returns successfully, but that looks like a terrible hack. And I don't know what `err` will contain if the function fails.

What's the recommended practice for handling API function return values? Should I ignore the `err` return value, set it to `nil` on successful return and do the `GetLastError` dance on failure?

There's some conflict between the Windows API way of handling errors and the Go way of handling/reporting them. I'm looking for advice from experienced Windows Go programmers on how best to resolve that conflict.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

// Windows MEMORYSTATUSEX structure
type MemoryStatusEx struct {
    dwLength                uint32
    dwMemoryLoad            uint32
    ullTotalPhys            uint64
    ullAvailPhys            uint64
    ullTotalPageFile        uint64
    ullAvailPageFile        uint64
    ullTotalVirtual         uint64
    ullAvailVirtual         uint64
    ullAvailExtendedVirtual uint64
}

type MemInfo struct {
    MemTotal uint64
    MemFree  uint64
    MemAvail uint64
}

func GetMemInfo() (minfo MemInfo, err error) {
    var winMemInfo MemoryStatusEx
    winMemInfo.dwLength = uint32(unsafe.Sizeof(winMemInfo))

    var mod = syscall.NewLazyDLL("kernel32.dll")
    var proc = mod.NewProc("GlobalMemoryStatusEx")

    ret, _, err := proc.Call(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&winMemInfo)))
    if ret == 0 {
        fmt.Printf("return value=%d\n", ret)
        return
    }
    // This is silly.
    // For some reason on successful return err is set to "The operation completed successfully"
    fmt.Println("error=", err)
    err = nil
    minfo.MemTotal = winMemInfo.ullTotalPhys
    minfo.MemFree = winMemInfo.ullTotalPhys - winMemInfo.ullAvailPhys
    minfo.MemAvail = winMemInfo.ullAvailPhys

    return
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("testing GetMemInfo()")
    minfo, err := GetMemInfo()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error getting memory info")
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Memory: total %d, free %d, avail %d\n", minfo.MemTotal, minfo.MemFree, minfo.MemAvail)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended to first check the return value for indications of a failed result, and then examine the error value. This follows a common practice for handling Win32 API calls.

For this GlobalMemoryStatusEx function, the MSDN says:

> If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.
> If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.

So the logic to handle the result would be:

```
ret, _, err := proc.Call(...)
if ret == 0 {
  return 0, err
} else {
  return ret, nil
}
```